# Test if sentences contain smaller sentences

Tags: python

So I have 100 million sentences, and for each sentence I'd like to see whether it contains one of 6000 smaller sentences (matching whole words only).  So far my code is

```
smaller_sentences = [...]
for large_sentence in file:
    for small_sentence in smaller_sentences:
        if ((' ' + small_sentence + ' ') in large_sentence)
                or (large_sentence.startswith(small_sentence + ' ')
                or (large_sentence.endswith(' ' + small_sentence):
            outfile.write(large_sentence)
            break
```

But this code runs prohibitively slowly.  Do you know of a faster way to go about doing this?

Comment: If you have 600 billion "string in string" tests to perform (which is literally trillions of comparisons), you're going to be hard pressed to find a fast solution no matter what. Not to say you should stick with this.

Comment: Well if it helps, I have access to a nice computing cluster, but then I would have to write my code in a different language, which would piss me off.

Comment: Well, my advice is that if you have to do ten trillion of anything, you do it any way you possibly can. Doing that sort of operation on a personal computer is probably not going to be feasible. But let's see what sort of responses you get.

Comment: If you've got a cluster to work with, you could use something like [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) to distribute the work across many nodes.

Comment: A solution that scales well is the [Rabin-Karp algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin-Karp_string_search_algorithm) which makes use of a rolling hash.

Comment: Define "sentence" and define "smaller" and longer. Are these actual words, or strings (eg. Gene sequences). And is smaller sentence 10 characters, 20, etc? Similarly, how long is a longer sentence?

Comment: Also, this algortihm will show only the first small sentence that a large sentence contains. If a large sentence contains two smaller sentences, you'll only see one. Is this right?

Comment: Lastly, what is this for? Are the lists of sentences changing or is this a one time thing? If you get more large sentences, can we cache the occurrence of small sentences for later retrieval?

Comment: @Lego Stormtroopr A sentence is a string of space-separated words.  All sentences (small and large) are guaranteed to be under 200 characters.  The small sentences probably won't change more than a couple times, but the large sentences may change more often.

Comment: I have to say I am immensely curious as to what you're doing, at this point.

Comment: one quick fix to avoid 3 tests in the inner loop is to add a space at each end of `large_sentence` for the check `' '+small_sentence+' ' in ' '+large_sentence+' '`.  But the nested loops are the real drain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing more about the domain (word/sentence length), frequency of read/write/query and specifics around the algorithm.

But, in the first instance you can switch your condition around.

This checks the whole string (slow), then the head (fast), then the tail (fast).

```
((' ' + small_sentence + ' ') in large_sentence)
        or (large_sentence.startswith(small_sentence + ' ')
        or (large_sentence.endswith(' ' + small_sentence):
```

This checks the head then the tail (fast), then the head (fast), then the whole string. Not huge bump in the Big-O sense, but it might add some speed if you know that the strings might be more likely at the start or finish.

```
(large_sentence.startswith(small_sentence + ' ')
        or (large_sentence.endswith(' ' + small_sentence)
        or ((' ' + small_sentence + ' ') in large_sentence)
```